# Toasts not displaying on button press

Tags: java, android, toast

I'm going through an example in a book and reading and have come across a problem I have a content_quiz.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/question_text" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/true_button"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/false_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and QuizActivity.java

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });

    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });

}
```

However when I run the app and tap the buttons nothing happens? I'm not sure what could be causing thing, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to call `show()` on your `Toast`s.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing it, for that you need to add `.show()`

```
Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: If it works you can mark it as accepted, thanks

Comment: I need to wait 20 mins before I can, but I will